# Unity 3D rotating a game object with the left stick causes object to Jitter back and forth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make a third person controller that uses the PS4 controller with the left stick controlling the rotation and movement and the right stick controlling the camera separately. my problem right now is that when I apply this script to my game object it causes the player to Jitter back and forth. Any thoughts as to why or how I can fix it thanks.

```
   void Update ()
{
    //Defaults to the left Stick
    float hAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
    float vAxis = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


    Vector3 NextDir = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis);

    if (NextDir != Vector3.zero)
    {

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(NextDir); //this rotates the character correclty but causes jitter
        transform.Translate(NextDir.x * Time.deltaTime * 5, NextDir.y * Time.deltaTime * 5, NextDir.z * Time.deltaTime * 5, Space.Self);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the "jitter" you see is the game code accurately rotating the object according to the data it is getting from the joystick.  I am guessing that by "jitter" you mean the rotation is bouncing back and forth between clockwise and counter-clockwise sporadically, when you think that you are smoothly rotating the joystick in one direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise).  (If not, please describe the jitter.)

If this is the case, since you are reading the joystick at every frame, the joystick is probably picking up values that cause the vector to bounce back and forth.  So, try adding a tolerance and only taking action if the vector changes by a certain amount.  Or, only accept vectors that cause the rotation to continue in the same direction (CW or CCW) as the previous frame, unless the change is more than some certain amount, which would indicate that the player really does want to start turning back in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the value of the dead property in the horizontal and vertical axis. This should mean the joystick has to be moved further out of it's resting position before reporting a value.

It's located in Edit->Project Settings->Input modify the value for the second occurrences of those two properties ( the first two are for the keyboard )